# Training data dimensions for semantic segmentation using CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, semantic-segmentation

I encountered many hardships when trying to fit a CNN (U-Net) to my tif training images in Python.

I have the following structure to my data:

- X
- - 0
- - - [Images] (tif, 3-band, 128x128, values ∈ [0, 255])
- X_val
- - 0
- - - [Images] (tif, 3-band, 128x128, values ∈ [0, 255])
- y
- - 0
- - - [Images] (tif, 1-band, 128x128, values ∈ [0, 255])
- y_val
- - 0
- - - [Images] (tif, 1-band, 128x128, values ∈ [0, 255])

Starting with this data, I defined ImageDataGenerators:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras as ks

    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    
    bs = 10 # batch size
    args_col = {"data_format" : "channels_last",
                "brightness_range" : [0.5, 1.5]
                }
    args_aug = {"rotation_range" : 365,
                "width_shift_range" : 0.05,
                "height_shift_range" : 0.05,
                "horizontal_flip" : True,
                "vertical_flip" : True,
                "fill_mode" : "constant",
                "featurewise_std_normalization" : False,
                "featurewise_center" : False
                }
    args_flow = {"color_mode" : "rgb",
                 "class_mode" : "sparse",
                 "batch_size" : bs,
                 "target_size" : (128, 128),
                 "seed" : 42
                 }
    # train generator
    X_generator = ks.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1.0/255.0,
                                                            **args_aug,
                                                            **args_col)
    X_gen = X_generator.flow_from_directory(directory = "my/directory/X",
                             **args_flow)
    
    y_generator = ks.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(**args_aug,
                                                            cval = NoDataValue)
    y_gen = y_generator.flow_from_directory(directory = "my/directory/y",
                             **args_flow, color_mode = "grayscale")
    
    train_generator = zip(X_gen, y_gen)
    # val generator
    X_val_generator = ks.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1.0/255.0)
    X_val_gen = X_generator.flow_from_directory(directory = "my/directory/X_val"),
                                 **args_flow)
    
    y_val_generator = ks.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()
    y_val_gen = y_generator.flow_from_directory(directory = "my/directory/y_val"),
                                 **args_flow, color_mode = "grayscale")
    
    val_generator = zip(X_val_gen, y_val_gen)
```

Using this generator, I can create pairs of training images and corresponding masks and visualize them like this:

```
    X, y = next(train_generator)
    X_test = X[0][0]
    y_test = y[0][0]
    
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
    plt.imshow(np.array(X_test))
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
    plt.imshow(np.array(y_test))
```

Resulting in:

[image: Visualization of ImageDataGenerator output]

However, I cannot train a U-Net, as I intended:

When I define a U-Net based on an [example](https://github.com/bnsreenu/python_for_microscopists/blob/master/074-Defining%20U-net%20in%20Python%20using%20Keras.py) from the internet (or basically any other example of a U-Net I've found) as `model` and then do the following:

```
model.compile(optimizer = "adam", loss = "sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics = ["accuracy"])
model.fit(train_generator, epochs = 5, steps_per_epoch = 10, validation_data = val_generator)
```

it will fail with the error:

```
ValueError: Layer model expects 1 input(s), but it received 2 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, None, None, None) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float32>]
```

I tried other loss functions and other `class_mode` arguments, but it always failed with some error related to the dimensions of the input data or the data passed between layers. An other example (when setting `class_mode = None`:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [16384,1] and labels shape [49152]
```

I just started getting into CNNs and Python, so I have no clue what to try further or how to resolve those errors. I was pretty sure I use the correct loss function, which seems to be often the problem when similar errors occur (I have multiple classes, hence the `"sparse_categorical_crossentropy"`).

Any ideas how to solve this and make the data fit the expected CNN input (or the other way round, depending on what the problem is)?

**Note:**
My `ImageDataGenerator` outputs a pair of images (X and y) with the following format (I noticed I had to set `color_mode` to "grayscale" for the masks (y)):

[image: Screenshot of training data format]

I used `keras.layers.Input(shape = (128, 128, 3))` in the example U-Net, since the [keras documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Input) states shape = "A shape tuple (integers), not including the batch size".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this particular problem. Amongst other issues, `"class_mode"` has to be set to `None` for this kind of model. With that set, the second array in both `X` and `y` is not written by the `ImageDataGenerator`. As a result, X and y are interpreted as the data and the mask (which is what we want) in the combined `ImageDataGenerator`. Otherwise, `X_val_gen` already produces the tuple shown in the screenshot, where the second entry is interpreted as the class, which would make sense in a classification problem with images spread out in various folders each labeled with a class ID.